# Enabling parents and dependencies of selected items recursively

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I have a class `Feature` as such:

```
public class Feature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public List<Feature> SubFeatures { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public string[] DependsOn { get; set; }

    public bool IsRole { get; set; }

    public bool ManuallySelected { get; set; }
}
```

The `DependsOn` contains the `Name` of any other `Features` it depends on.

A `Feature` can only have a single parent (not seen directly at the `Feature` level, to find out what the parent of any given `Feature` is need to find out which `Feature` lists the child `Feature` as a `SubFeature`).

I then hold a `List<Feature>` containing all possible features in a var named `myFeatures`.

I then display these `Feature` to the user in a `TreeListView` (part of `ObjectListView`).

So far, so good. The problem is that I want to ensure that when a user selects a `Feature`, both the parent(s) of that `Feature` and the dependencies of that `Feature` (and parent(s) of the dependencies, and dependencies of the dependencies and parent(s) of the dependencies' dependencies ... etc) are also selected.

I also identify which `Features` a user selected manually (using `ManuallySelected` property) so that if they unselect any `Feature` at all, any parents and dependencies (and subdependencies and their parents etc) are also unselected, unless needed by any other `Feature` that was manually selected.

So this is my code for when the user click the `CheckBox` of a `Feature`...

```
treeListView1.CheckStatePutter = (rowObject, value) =>
{
    if (rowObject is Feature feature)
    {
        feature.Enabled = value == CheckState.Checked;
        feature.ManuallySelected = feature.Enabled;

        var flatFeatures = FlattenFeatures(_thisOperatingSystem.Features).ToList();

        foreach (var nonSelectedFeature in flatFeatures.Where(x => !x.ManuallySelected))
        {
            nonSelectedFeature.Enabled = false;
        }

        foreach (var selectedFeature in flatFeatures.Where(x => x.ManuallySelected))
        {
            foreach (var subFeature in GetFeatureDependencies(flatFeatures, selectedFeature))
            {
                subFeature.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        treeListView1.Refresh();
    }

    return value;
};
```

And these are the helper functions that handle all recursion:

```
public IEnumerable<Feature> GetFeatureDependencies(List<Feature> flatFeatures, Feature feature)
{
    foreach (var parent in GetFeatureParents(flatFeatures, feature).Where(x => x != null))
    {
        yield return parent;

        foreach (var parentDependency in GetFeatureDependencies(flatFeatures, parent))
        {
            yield return parentDependency;
        }
    }

    foreach (var dependencyName in feature.DependsOn)
    {
        foreach (var dependency in flatFeatures.Where(x => x.Name == dependencyName))
        {
            yield return dependency;

            foreach (var parent in GetFeatureParents(flatFeatures, dependency).Where(x => x != null))
            {
                yield return parent;

                foreach (var parentDependency in GetFeatureDependencies(flatFeatures, parent))
                {
                    yield return parentDependency;
                }
            }

            foreach (var subDependency in GetFeatureDependencies(flatFeatures, dependency))
            {
                yield return subDependency;

                foreach (var parent in GetFeatureParents(flatFeatures, subDependency).Where(x => x != null))
                {
                    yield return parent;

                    foreach (var parentDependency in GetFeatureDependencies(flatFeatures, parent))
                    {
                        yield return parentDependency;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Feature> GetFeatureParents(List<Feature> flatFeatures, Feature feature)
{
    var parent = flatFeatures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubFeatures.Contains(feature));

    yield return parent;

    if (parent == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var parentsParent in GetFeatureParents(flatFeatures, parent))
    {
        yield return parentsParent;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Feature> FlattenFeatures(IEnumerable<Feature> features)
{
    foreach (var feature in features)
    {
        yield return feature;

        foreach (var child in FlattenFeatures(feature.SubFeatures))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

The code works, but I think somewhere I made this far more complicated than it should be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The correct question title, which states your concern about the code, is too common to be useful. Our site standard is for the title to state what the code does — see [ask].

Comment: @200_success I'd love for you to provide alternative titles, I think the title sucks too. That being said, I struggled to explain the issue in over 1000 characters, what makes you think I can do it in less than 1/10 of that?

Comment: Summarizing code is an important programming skill. Naming things succinctly and descriptively is hard!